# layout "scaleType" to center bottom align an image

Tags: android, layout, imageview

How can I show an image view on the screen that is horizontally center aligned vertically bottom aligned.

So far I tried something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#FFffff00"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/hand"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>
```

It works good on a mobile device, but on a tablet the image is horizontally aligned to the right of the screen.

Comment: In android you can provide alternative resources for example and XML for landscape (for tablet) and for potrait like most phone. Also you can also set in your manifest that your activity should be potrait only. not landscape like a table.??Or you can make scaleType to centerCrop or fit XY .What option do you want to give an answer?

Comment: Seems a bit overkill to give another resource for such a simple layout. I can set it to be portrait only, but it will be nice to support both orientations. centerCrop is not good, since I do not want to crop the image. fitXY is not good since I do not want to change image proportions.

Comment: Ooops my little head is lacking more alternatives!